# CR1632 (3v) vs. Two AA's

Tags: power-supply, batteries

Kind of a newbie at this, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I've disassembled a small lifeline alert pendant transmitter that normally runs on a CR1632, can I replace it with two AA's? Are there any disadvantages? Do CR batteries last longer, have more capacity than AA's, etc.?

On a separate note, if I want to replace the batteries with a power supply, can I use a 5v USB supply or would I have to look for a 3v supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single 3.0v CR1632 Lithium coin battery has a capacity of about 125 mAh.  A single 1.5v AA Alkaline battery has a capacity if about 2500 mAh.  So you can replace a CR1632 by two Alkaline AA's (in series), and they will last twenty times longer.  A single non-rechargeable Lithium AA battery, like the [Energizer Ultimate Lithium](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/l91.pdf), has slightly more capacity at 3000 mAh.  They would last longer than Alkaline batteries in low-usage situations.

I can't see of any disadvantages other than the physical differences.

If you wanted to run it off a power supply, you want want to use 3.0v (not 3.3v).

You could use a LDO (low dropout) regulator to generate 3v from a 5v USB supply.  One suitable device would be the [Microchip MCP1702](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22008E.pdf) which will deliver 250 mA of current (plenty, considering the pendant is designed to run off a coin cell).  The regulator is available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1240=445&pv1240=103&pv1240=16&pv1240=343&pv1240=879&pv1240=970&pv1240=92&pv1240=1051&pv1240=456&pv1240=664&pv1240=404&pv1240=1078&pv1240=774&pv1240=3&pv1240=421&pv127=4588&pv127=4589&pv127=4590&pv127=4591&pv127=4592&pv127=4593&pv127=4594&pv127=4595&pv127=4542&pv127=4596&pv127=4076&pv127=4077&pv127=4606&pv127=4572&pv127=4598&pv127=4599&pv127=3056&pv127=4566&pv127=4814&pv127=4863&pv127=4547&pv127=4602&pv127=4573&pv127=4541&pv127=4605&pv127=5806&pv127=5769&pv127=6290&pv127=5985&pv127=6071&pv127=5454&pv127=5546&pv127=6024&pv127=5160&pv127=5836&pv127=5277&pv127=5381&pv127=5116&pv69=80&FV=fff40027%2Cfff80182%2Cc0004e%2C2040019%2C204001a%2C204001b%2C2040039%2C204003a%2C204003d%2C2040043%2C2040049%2C204004a%2C204004b%2C204004c%2C204004d%2C2040051%2C2040053%2C204005a%2C204005f%2C2040062%2C2040063%2C2040070%2C2040071%2C2040073%2C204007d%2C204007e%2C2040081%2C2040082%2C20400a7%2C20400b0%2C20400be%2C20400fd%2C2040103%2C204014a%2C2040153%2C204015a%2C2040166%2C204016c%2C204016f%2C20401ca%2C20401cb%2C2040233%2C204024e%2C20402ad%2C20402e9%2C2040373%2C20403a4%2C20403a5%2C20403a8%2C20403ac%2C20403b2%2C20403bf%2C20403d6%2C20403d7%2C20403dc%2C20403e6%2C20403e7%2C20403e9%2C20403f7%2C20403f8%2C20403f9%2C204040b%2C2040414%2C2040465%2C204049f%2C20404a0%2C20404aa%2C2040720%2C2040721%2C2040726%2C204074b%2C2040754%2C10a40002&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: Super Power Supply® AC / DC Adapter Charger Cord for Roland PSB-6U PSB-6U-120 Boss Wall Plug https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DRF32D2/ref=cm_sw_r_awd_YJFivb126S85M https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DRF32D2/ref=cm_sw_r_awd_YJFivb126S85M

Comment: This *should* work.  My concern, is your pendant is drawing so little power, sometimes these "wall-warts" are not well regulated on little or no loads.  If you have a multimeter, I would check the output to make sure it is not over 3v.  (If you don't have a meter, add [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Sienoc-Digital-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Multimeter/dp/B00F91BQTE/ref=sr_1_80?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1428290397&sr=1-80&keywords=multimeter) for only $7 to your order.)

Comment: thanks for the advice. I do see a regulated 3v supply from Amazon. It's rated 1.5a though.

Comment: The amperage rating doesn't matter that much in your case (just needs to be over a few hundred milliamps); main thing is that the supply is truly regulated with no load (since your load is so small).

Comment: I ended up going with this one http://www.radioshack.com/enercell-3v-700ma-regulated-ac-adapter/2730312.html#.VSJtB5PF99J&tab=tab3 and it appears to be doing the trick. It's a solid 3v on my meter.

Answer (score 3):

Lithium cells have a extremely low self discharge rates therefore they are used in applications that demand less current over a long time. Examples are portable thermometers, watches, etc.

Alkaline batteries are used where in-rush current needed is high. Examples are digital cameras. Alkaline batteries have a self discharge rate higher than the Lithium cells.

Your Application:
It all depends upon your application if you want to use Lithium or Alkaline cells (battery if replacing a 3V source). In case of your application of a lifeline pendant, it would be wise to use Lithium cell.

1. Portability: First you do not want two AA cells dangling on your neck.
2. Low current requirements: Second your application doesn't require that high current.
3. Discharge rate: Third your application needs a longer life and low self discharge 
   rates

Lastly, there are AA Lithium cells (low discharge) available in the market. You can use them if you have to:

[image: Lithium AA]

Comment: great points. this project is actually in a box. the pendant has been modified so that it can be triggered by relay. I'm going back and forth on lithium AAs or a regulated 3v supply.

Answer (score 2):

The pendant most likely contains a voltage regulator, in low-power circuits these often have specifications way above what is actually needed, so it is quite possible that the voltage regulator will work with a 5V input, if you can find the IC and read the part number, you can probably find a datasheet with the relevant info.

There will be some ripple in the output of your power supply, that could be an issue if the device is ripple-sensitive, if it is a problem you could add in a capacitor, charge it through a resistor, and draw directly from it.

As tcrosley mention, too low load could be a problem for the power supply, it may cause over-voltage and/or ripple. The simple solution is to insert a dummy load, a resistor that draws some power from the supply.

The following diagram shows the solutions I have mentioned, it may not all be necessary, the solution still depend on the device containing a suitable regulator, and the component values are mostly guesses, they may need to be changed depending on the specifications of the device and power supply. It is a somewhat crude solution, only suitable for low power circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjxPzo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If the pendant is designed to work off a 3v coin cell, why would it have a voltage regulator?  Sorry, that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @tcrosley Because battery voltage drops as the battery is drained. If you want to feed the circuit a constant voltage you need some way of compensating for the voltage difference. A normal "1.5V" battery for instance will typically start its life at approximately 1.65V, and it can be drained down to around 1.1V before the current you can draw from it is so low that it is useless.

Comment: I would agree if the pendant was designed to be run off an Alkaline cell.  It was not.  It was designed to run off a CR1632 Lithium coin cell, which does *not* lose its voltage gradually but rather it [drops off rapidly](http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/crseries_datasheets_merged.pdf) at the end.

Comment: @tcrosley It is indeed different curves, but there is still a voltage drop, and it is also clear to see that there is other factors that influence the voltage, the temperature makes quite a mark on some of those batteries. Of course, if the circuit can run on a broad enough voltage range there is no need for a regulator. As far as I can tell from the specs you need to support 2.5V to 3.3V to be on the safe side.